# Is it really necessary that every App need a Splash before entering the main page?

Tags: android, android-activity

Just a question jump out of my mind, is it ok that I use an image cover the main content page of my app, and when UI are ready, I can simply remove it, don't need to pass through the splash activity

I haven't tried, did anyone do the same things before?

Comment: The OS forces a splash screen on Android 12 and higher, see https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate